# SQL Server generates a query plan with parallelism and TOP statement

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, parallelism

I have two simple queries:

```
SELECT TOP(20) * FROM Clients ORDER BY City
```

```
SELECT TOP(20) Id, Name, City FROM Clients ORDER BY City
```

In the first case I get a result like this

| Id | Name | City | many more columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | Person 6 | NULL | ... |
| 2 | Person 2 | NULL | ... |
| 3 | Person 3 | NULL | ... |

In the second case I get a result like this
In the first case I get a result like this

| Id | Name | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Person 2 | NULL |
| 3 | Person 3 | NULL |
| 6 | Person 6 | NULL |

Notice that the order is different. Of course I understand that beacuse City is NULL for these three persons a unique order is not necessarily garantueed.

However, upon inspecting the query plans I noticed that the first query used parallelism
[image]

The second query did not:

[image]

After reading the documentation about [parallel query processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver16#parallel-query-processing), it specifically mentions that certain constructs inhibit parallelism, such as the TOP operator.

The only notable difference, apart form parralelism, is that the Top N Sort node of the parallelised plan has an estimated I/O cost of 16, while the Top N Sort node of the non-parallelised query plan has only an estimated I/O cost of 0.01

So my question is: why would it still use parallelism here when I use the TOP operator, even though microsoft stating it should inhibit the mechanism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### bottoms up

The documentation in that section is a total disaster.

The TOP operator only introduces a *serial zone* in the plan where it is consumes data. That's exactly what your plan shows, with the Gather Streams operator prior to the TOP operator.

Note that a TOP N Sort operator is not restricted in the same way as (presentation) TOP is in forcing a parallel zone.

[image: NUTS]